# References for maximizing a product under a sum equality constraint and individual variable inequality constraints

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

I am looking for references on the following optimization problem:

maximize $\prod x_i$ under a sum constraint $\sum x_i = 1$ and individual variable constraints $0 \le x_i \le C_i$.

I know the analytic solution (it's pretty simple), but I would love to find a citation on this problem (or some version of it).

Comment: Do you know what the [technique AM-GM](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean-am-gm/) is? If you also have $x_i > 0$, that should do the trick.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, $x_i \ge 0$, so AM-GM seems to be a good start. Your link does not cover the individual variable constraints though.

Comment: Ah. You should mention that the solution would be $x_i = C_i$ for low values of $C_i$ and $x_j$ are constant otherwise. I would say that the easiest approach is simply partial differentiation.